# Interface implementation array and calling extra functions

Tags: go

I have some concept of services in my application
Services interface is defined as follows

```
type Service interface {
    // Init and Start the Service
    Start() error
    // Start the Service
    // Stops the Service
    Stop() error        
}
```

Implemented couple of type using this interface

```
type Service1 struct {  
}
func NewService1() *Service1 {
    return &MediaService{}
}
func (m *Service1) Start() error {
}
func (m *Service1) Stop() error {
}
func (m *Service1) Fn1() error {
}
```

and

```
type Service2 struct {  
    }
    func NewService2() *Service2 {
        return &MediaService{}
    }
    func (m *Service2) Start() error {
    }
    func (m *Service2) Stop() error {
    }
    func (m *Service2) Fn2() error {
    }
```

Storing all the instance in a array

```
Services = make([]Service, 2)

    Services[0] = NewService1()
    Services[1] = NewService2()
```

But I cannot call extra function defined in services.

`Services[0].Fn1` or `Services[1].Fn2`

Comment: Because `Service` does not contain those "extra" methods, and in your current setup not all services implement all. E.g. `Services[0]` does not have `Fn2()`, so you could not call that. If you need to check the dynamic type of the service and call extra methods, you may use type assertions, e.g. `if s, ok := Services[0].(Service1); ok { s.Fn1() }`. You may also type assert an interface type containing `Fn()` method instead of the concrete type. If this use is not feasible to you, you have to redesign.

Comment: Note that this has _nothing_ to do with arrays or slices. A variable of type `Service` has exactly two methods `Start` and `Stop`. The fact that the variable contains a `Service1` is hidden as this is the whole purpose of interface variables. Take a look at https://tour.golang.org/methods/9 ff.

Comment: Thanks @volker , is there any alternative approach achieve like this ?

Comment: No. You can type-assert or type-switch to get hand on the type stored in the interface and that is is (except for mimicking this via reflection).

Comment: If you're trying to call `Services[0].Fn1` at all, then you need to reconsider the design. A `[]Service` is correct if you're treating it as a list of arbitrary services, but you're not; you're trying to treat each index as a specific service with specific functionality, which means most likely they should be distinct variables of different types, not a slice you index into with magic numbers.

Answer (score 2):

`Services = make([]Service, 2)` means that you have an array of the interface `Service`

It doesn't really matter which `Service` implementations you add as long the implementation fulfills the `Service` contract, namingly `Start() error` and `Stop() error`

When you get a service from that array with:

`Services[0]`

at compile time this if of the type `Service` and therefor you can only access all functions of `Service`.

At runtime, the actual type behind `Services[0]` is `NewService1` or maybe another one  but this doesn't really matter because you specified the `Services` Array to be of type `Service` and therefor can only access those functions.

If you really want to call `Fn1`, you have to make assumptions which actual type is behind the single array fields and cast them:

`Services[0].(*Service1).Fn1()`

---

If you want do avoid panics at runtime because of invalid casts (when a different type if actually available as you expect), please have a look here how you make type assertions https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions